# How to rotate image to its next degree on button click event?

Tags: jquery, html, css, rotation, transform

I am playing with [jquery.rotate.js](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-rotate/) and I want to rotate image everytime to next rotation degree.

I have included following jquery librarys:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.rotate.1-1.js'></script>
```

jQuery Code:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    $("body").on("click", "#button", function() {
        $(".north").rotate(a());
    });
    nextAngle = 0;
    function a() {
        nextAngle += 90;
        if (nextAngle >= 360) nextAngle = 0;
        return nextAngle;
    }
});
```

HTML Code:

```
<img class="north" src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSGPgQ8k88yaWVPRytT957hKLV-89QmZtkZc44q45TEDdqe9sKwqg">
<input type="button" id="button" value="Rotate me">
```

My JSFiddle: [Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/9r6j7f6d/)

In my current code, image is rotating only one time but I want to reotate image everytime on button click event. How it will be possible with `jQuery.rotate.js`?

### I Want Image Rotation Like This Sequence:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any Idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make changes in Jquery like following will work for your:

```
$("body").on("click", "#button", function () {
    $(".north, canvas").rotate(getNextAngle());
});
```

Because on click of rotate your image is converted to canvas.

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r6j7f6d/1/)

**Edit:**

Change in JQuery as following to get your desired output as you mention in your question image.

```
$("body").on("click", "#button", function () {
    $(".north, canvas").rotate(90);
});
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9r6j7f6d/2/)

Comment: I have checked your JSFiddle but somting is wrong. Image rotation is not working properway.

Comment: I have update my question with explaning image sequence.

Comment: I have one queston. What is the use of `canvas` inside this `$(".north, canvas").rotate(90);`

Comment: As mention in my answer when you first click on rotate me button your image(img tag) is converted to canvas. So, it is not rotating on your second click. `$(".north, canvas").rotate(90);` means on click rotate that canvas.